# Is it possible to walk from Gatwick Airport station to Travelodge Gatwick?

Tags: airport-transfer, walking, lgw

Is it possible to walk from Gatwick Airport station to Travelodge Gatwick, or other hotels in the area? Or if I need to take a bus, does the bus have rooms for luggages?

Comment: I've done it. There were a couple of places where pulling a heavy case was inconvenient though. I'm sure the hotel shuttle buses have plenty of room for luggage. I can't remember why I decided to walk.

Comment: These are the only hotels really in the airport - the list is **right here** http://www.gatwickairport.com/hotels/Airport-hotels/  South: Bloc Premier Yotel, North Hampton Premier Sofitel

Comment: 700 meters walk from drop off point to Luton airport's National express bus stop with two suitcases was the last time I would ever walk with luggage. Not a good idea I would say.

Answer (score 16):

Having made the journey in both directions only yesterday, I can confirm that this is a fairly easy 10 minute walk but since the route of about 200m nearest the Travelodge is designated as the West Sussex nature trail this doesn't have hard footings and is, by its nature, uneven and potentially a bit muddy after rain. The rest of the walk is on hard pavement which requires crossing two light traffic roads. Thus, if you are carrying a heavy suitcase or unable to carry a small trolley bag, unsure in your footing and consider that there is poor lighting on the nature trail section at night, you would be better off taking a transport suggested above.

Leaving the Gatwick north terminal arrivals and with the multi-storey car park in front of you, bear left and skirt the car park keeping it to your right, Pass the Premier Inn, also on your right and cross a narrow road coming from your left. Continue on bearing left when you will turn a bend where you will see a petrol station on the right. You will also see the Travelodge in the distance. Cross the road at the designated crossing point just short of a roundabout where the combined entrance for the Premier Inn (A24) and Northgate staff car park is on your right. The car park is enclosed in a wire security fence. Cross the entrance road. At this point you are on a grass verge with a well beaten path. Keeping the wire fence immediately on your right continue walking towards the point where the fence takes a 90 degree turn to the right. You are now on the nature trail between the fence and some shrubbery. Turn at the end and continue to follow the path with the fence on your right and trees on the left. At the point where the fence takes another 90 degree turn to the right, there is a path that dives into the trees on your left. Follow this path which is on a slight incline when you will come across a footbridge over the river. Having crossed the river, you are immediately in the SE corner of the Travelodge car park. Skirting the Travelodge you come to reception.

Comment: Peter Roy, I park in that Staff Car park ('Y' car park) when I'm working in the North Terminal and I must say your directions are really clear.

Comment: Nice explanation. Is this https://i.imgur.com/A4cBNOW.png illustration correct for the nature trail you need to take? https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/73730/4188 mentioned this but yours is a much more detailed description.

Answer (score 8):

Travelodge runs shuttle buses. Fares are £3.00 per adult, one way and £1.50 per child (5-15 years old), one way.You will have to call up the hotel to let them know that you are waiting at the pick up point.

It is a long way from the airport, not a walking distance by any standards especially when you have luggage.

Getting a taxi would be cheaper if you are two adults or more but do not get a taxi from the airport taxi desk, call up some company like Alpha cars from Crawley instead and it would work out a lot cheaper.

Comment: OK, I checked Travelodge website, and indeed there are shuttle buses but apparently they are not free: _Fares are £3.00 per adult, one way and £1.50 per child (5-15 years old), one way._ Looks comparable to a taxi if there are two adults, yes?

Comment: Thanks for correcting, I have edited my answer. Getting a taxi will only be cheaper if you call a taxi company from outside the airport.

Answer (score 6):

The travel lodge looks a little far away to me, however having recently dropped off my car for parking directly outside the Premier Inn I can confirm that both the [Premier Inn](https://goo.gl/maps/gixSriPqKp32) and the Sofitel are onsite and easily accessible from the terminal by foot (I was using the North Terminal but it's also pretty easy to get between terminals on the inter-terminal transit shuttle).

Comment: Also note the per hour bookable Yotel *inside* the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at google maps, it appears to be possible to go from the airport to the train station, and take a footpath North West towards Riverside Garden Park. Switching to google streetview, there is a footpath along the North East side of London Road which can be followed to the North West towards the Travelodge at the junction of London Road and Povey Cross Road. It looks like it shouldn't be more than a 10 minute walk.

My proposed route is [shown here](http://www.gmap-pedometer.com/?r=6864397) at a little over a mile, so more like 20 minutes to walk.

Comment: Google actually estimates 28 mins rather than 10. https://maps.google.com/?daddr=Gatwick%20Airport%20Station%2C%20Gatwick%20Airport%2C%20Horley%2C%20Crawley%2C%20West%20Sussex%20RH6%200RD&ftid=0x4875f01da4a93283:0x723a8d8bc6f3e94b;0x4875f02730ca946d:0xaa77a1cd73a8045e&dirflg=w&saddr=Travelodge%20Gatwick%20Airport%20Central%20Hotel%2C%20Povey%20Cross%20Road%2C%20Horley

Comment: Yes, I used Google Maps, too, but I wasn't too sure about it. The suggested path seems to cross some motorway. Are you sure that this really is possible?

Comment: The train station is inside the airport. @MartinSmith indeed it does look more than 10 minutes. If you want to walk it would be better to get the monorail to North Terminal and walk from there. It's not given as a walking route but by car it's 0.6 miles so that way it is about 10 minutes (plus monorail). Parminder's answer is better: call for the hotel courtesy bus.

Comment: I agree, 10 minutes is too optimistic. I'd originally used what google said as Gatwick airport to the travelodge rather than the train station. Calculating a map on gmap-pedometer puts it just over a mile to the roundabout:http://www.gmap-pedometer.com/?r=6864397

Comment: @adipro You can search trip advisor reviews for the word "walk" here to get some experiences https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g191265-d229508-Reviews-Travelodge_Gatwick_Airport_Central-Horley_Surrey_England.html do

Answer (score 5):

So I don’t recommend doing this walk at night, or when it’s raining, or with heavy luggage. A better alternative would be to take the train to or from Horley Station and walk 15-20 minutes along Brighton Road and Massetts Road, it’s way more straightforward and is paved.

That out of the way, this is the route from the Travelodge to Gatwick Station / South Terminal.

Ironically to get to the North Terminal, you still have to take this route and get the free shuttle link despite it being closer.

When you pass the Esso petrol station at the roundabout, you can cross the road at the designated pedestrian crossings, then walk down London Road.

Eventually you’ll get to a small bridge that goes over the River Mole and the pavement ends there. However on the left [there is a small winding and somewhat  steep footpath here](https://maps.app.goo.gl/WcxvNsCqvmyhtcvR8?g_st=ic). This is probably the most challenging part of this walk.

[[image: London Road over Mole River bridge][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNflZ.jpg)

[image: ramp pathway]

This will lead you to a footpath that runs parallel between the Gatwick Stream and London Road. It’s a nice walk, with plenty of tree cover, hence you can’t see on satellite imagery but it provides excellent shade in the summer.

[image: woodlands footpath]

You basically keep following this path  until you reach a foot tunnel that goes under the road.

[image: random brick building next to foot tunnel]

[image: the foot tunnel, north entrance]

on the other side it goes under the shuttle line

[image: the foot tunnel, south entrance]

[image: map]

At this point, you’re pretty much in the vicinity of the airport, right next to the South Terminal shuttle station. There’s a stairwell at this end that will take you right up into the station, where you can go wherever within the airport easily: south terminal, north terminal, rail station, etc.

[image: South Terminal shuttle station]

Answer (score 2):

I have never done it but doing some research if you walk to the corner of the Premier Inn Car Park and into the trees there is a small bridge over the River Mole  4 steps up and 4 down this brings you at the Travelodge Car Park . There is a local bus starts at 3 am for £1.60 each free if you have a bus pass OAP. Fastaway bus 100 stops at the North and South Terminals

Comment: You can read a very detailed description of this walk at https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/176898/4188

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would work and would take no more than 15 minutes from Gatwick North Terminal. Follow directions to Premier Inn London Gatwick Airport A23 Airport Way an easy 10 minute walk from the North Terminal which I have done many times. Going through the trees across the River Mole to the Travelodge Car Park could be a challenge if you have luggage and it is wet.